# Passing Eval() as parameter vs calling from codebehind

Tags: asp.net, eval

I've seen Eval() being both called as a parameter such is in a Repeater 
`<%#DoMethod(Eval("field"))%>` and then in the codebehind

```
protected string DoMethod(object eval)
{
    return .....
}
```

but I've also seen just

```
protected string DoMethod()
{
    string field = Eval("field").ToString();
    return .....
}
```

which is better?

My initial guess would be the second since this could aid debugging, but I've also heard the first way is better.